# How do I get this metric clock to repaint every tic

Tags: java, canvas, repaint

First time actually asking a question on stack overflow. This one has really quite stumped me.
Basically, I have the code for a clock I'm making just for fun, but after the first paint, it doesn't update. I have a comment in the code where I would want the update to run, but no matter what I put there, it doesn't actually call the paint method (otherwise it would print "day be light"). The clock does run though (I cut out the part that actually prints out the time to save on space when uploading). What do you think? 
You should be able to copy and run that code, resulting in a filled circle and an integer in a window. if the graphics would update, that integer would theoretically change...but it doesn't.
And yes, I'm trying to make this resizable but stay square. that may be part of my problem.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.time.Clock;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class toUpload extends Canvas {

    static Clock tickClock;
    static long dmillis;
    static String lastTick;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3836576462912965111L;
    private static Rectangle rect;
    static JFrame mainFrame;
    static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    static double numberDistance;
    static double sDistance;
    static double mDistance;
    static double hDistance;
    static int Hour = 0;
    static int Minute = 0;
    static int Second = 0;
    static int testing = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        toUpload t = new toUpload();
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setTitle("Metric Clock");
        mainFrame.setResizable(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        rect = mainFrame.getBounds();
        mainFrame.add(t);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.pack();
        resize();
        mainFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() 
        { public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
            int size = evt.getComponent().getSize().width;
            /*try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            mainFrame.setSize(size, size);
            resize();
        }
                @Override public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
                @Override public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
                @Override public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
        });
        startTic();
        while(true) {
            tic();
            //repaint, but for some reason I can't get it to repaint
            testing++; //just something to change to show whether or not the graphics are updating.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    private static void resize() {
        rect.height = mainFrame.getBounds().height-39;
        rect.width = mainFrame.getBounds().width-16;
        mainFrame.repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        System.out.println("day be light");

        g.clearRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        g.fillOval(50,50,100,100);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(testing),50,200);
        //does more stuff with painting
    }

    public static void tic() {

        //does stuff


    }
    public static void startTic() {
        //does stuff
    }


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't overrid `paint`. Only `paintComponent`. And you shouldn't do things like this in a loop, you should use a `java.swing.Timer`.

Comment: was planning to use a timer later, but this was a quick drop in to at least get things moving. I'll look into overriding paintComponent.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out (been working on this since yesterday, and only just now remembered....I made an object with the name "t" as you can see in the code. never intended to call it directly, so I made it a non-descriptive name. Never do that, folks.
calling `t.repaint();` works fine.